# Geoserver access REST in javascript - Why 403 Forbidden?

Tags: javascript, rest, geoserver

The [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/index.html) of the Geoserver mentions about REST examples.
I managed to achieve that using PHP. But I fail with Javascript. It show Status Code 403, which means Forbidden.

[image]

Here's my javascript pure code:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       // Action to be performed when the document is read;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", urlGeo, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy");
xhttp.send();
```

Here's my jquery ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
url: urlGeo,
type: 'POST',
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy");
},
success: function (res) { console.log('res',res); },
error: function (err) { 
console.log('err',err);
}
});
```

Both fail miserably. The thing is, no secret about the username and password. I am using the default for testing:

```
username: admin
password: geoserver
```

In this case, basic authorization is applied. `Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy` is being converted from `btoa(username:password)`.

So, I wonder why it fails in Javascript?

Comment: @Quentin
Yes it seems you have pointed out that "GET" becomes "OPTIONS" is the root cause. But I also hope that you can tell why it happens in javascript, but not PHP?

In PHP, it is using CURL. I thought it is equivalent to HTTP request in javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068